# can't connect to smtp server in development environment

Tags: java, email, netbeans

so here's the problem I'm having:

When I'm trying to connect to an smtp sever, and when I try it in netbeans, it gives me an error saying I can't connect:

I know that my computer can connect to the mail server, since telnet works perfectly fine when I try it, which makes me think the issue is with the code.

However when the program I wrote is used on a different computer, it works just fine. According to wireshark, the program never tried to connect to the mail server.

I've tried making myself an administrator on the firewall, and that has no affect on the program.

here's the code I'm using:

```
private static final Properties SYS_PROPS = System.getProperties();

public void sendEmail(String user, String Message, String subject, String recipient) throws ResourceException {
     try {
        //Set the host property
        SYS_PROPS.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "host");

        System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack" , "true");

        //Create a session for all the emails
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(SYS_PROPS);
        //Get the name of the contact peep
        String name = user;

            //Create a new message
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            MimeMultipart multiPart = new MimeMultipart();

            //Set to, from, and subject
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("http://localhost:8084/appName"));
            message.addRecipient(RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipient));
            message.setSubject(subject);

            //Next, add the message part
            BodyPart arm = new MimeBodyPart();

            arm.setContent(Message, "text/html");
            multiPart.addBodyPart(arm);

            //Set the multipart to the message
            message.setContent(multiPart);

            //Send the message
            Transport.send(message);

    } catch (MessagingException ex) {
        log(ex);
    }
}
```

My current theory is that I somehow have to configure netbeans, or tomcat, to allow me to send mail.

I would really appreciate any help that you can give!

I'm getting this error when I use the program:

```
SEVERE: null
com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: 10.1.0.5, 25; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: connect: Address is invalid on local machine, or port is not valid on remote machine
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1984)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:656)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:345)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:226)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:175)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:253)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at com.echoman.saasadmin.dao.EmailDao.sendEmail(EmailDao.java:347)
    at com.echoman.saasadmin.services.TenantService.SendEmail(TenantService.java:229)
    at com.echoman.saasadmin.form.EmailForm$2.buttonClick(EmailForm.java:148)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:508)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:198)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:161)
    at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:979)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:393)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button$1.click(Button.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:168)
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:118)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:287)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:180)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:93)
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1402)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:305)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: connect: Address is invalid on local machine, or port is not valid on remote machine
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:301)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:229)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1950)
    ... 52 more
```

this is my IP config

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection
Media State:Media Disconnected
Connection-Specic DNS Suffix:


Ethernet adapter Ethernet:
Connection-specific DNS Suffix :echoman.local
Ipv4 Address :10.1.2.15
Subnet mask :255.255.252.0
Default GateWay :10.1.0.5
```

Comment: This sounds like a firewall issue. I would try disabling it completely to see if that lets you through.

Comment: I tried making myself an administrator on the firewall, but that didn't seem to have any affect on the program. I can't try disabling the firewall because I'm testing this on a company computer. When monitoring the firewall I found that the mail server wasn't getting any request to send mail from the program

Comment: Is "host" actually the name of your smtp server?

Comment: no, it's actually an IP address, I was told to modify the code before posting it

Comment: Is this a network firewall or one running on your local machine? I'm going to suspect the issue is the local machine. Also, it would help if you supplied the exact error message you're getting.

Comment: This is a firewall on the network, I'll modify the question to have the error

Comment: And you definitely have no firewall on your local machine? No antivirus software installed? AVG, for instance, has a firewall. Windows also has a firewall ( [link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/turn-windows-firewall-on-off#turn-windows-firewall-on-off=windows-7). Try temporarily disabling any local firewalls.

Comment: I have tried disabling my windows firewall and antivirus, and that has no effect on the program

Comment: Can you add your output from ipconfig? [Instructions](http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f138/how-to-run-an-ipconfig-all-command-655357.html)

Comment: It's added to the question

Comment: The `setFrom` IP should be that of your computer's **external IP**. Otherwise you will be getting problems nonetheless: other servers blocking your emails and so on. If you read the error, that would match too.

Comment: I just tried setting the set From to be my external IP, and I got the exact same error. I'm using the exact same host and sender as the other computer I tested it on and that worked. The other computer I tested it on was on the same network. If it helps that computer was a mac and I'm using windows 8, but I don't think that's the problem

Comment: Try running the program from the command line, making sure to pass in the `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` parameter right after the java command. If that doesn't work, try the same thing but running command prompt as an administrator first.

Comment: I can't actually run the program from the command line, so I tried debugging it, and verified that the property perfer Ipv4 is set.

I'm trying to use code I got online to send mail to send mail from my gmail but it's giving me a anthentication Failed Exception, so it did connnect